# starter questions with docusign auth/clickwrap php api

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement the clickwrap process  and am using the php SDK.

When going through Auth via the Authorization Code Grant method and as part of the process it is asking for a login before completing the process. I've used my dev account details however why is this step needed as we are already passing through various keys/id?

Is this specific to the development environment or will this also happen in prod?

What will be presented to the end-user who does not have a Docusign Account?

I understand the 'obtain user consent' and can work that into the workflow but this is confusing.
I have worked through the Quickstart app as well and that has the same process. Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a page on your application to include a DocuSign clickwrap agreement, then you do not need to use the Click api. (It really should be named the Click Management API.)

What you do: follow the instructions for adding a clickwrap agreement shown in the [Click User Guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/click-user-guide).

The [Click Q & A page](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-Click) is also helpful.

The "Click API" is only needed if you want to programmatically look up the Click agreements, modify the Click configuration, etc.

Comment: That's helped. I knew i missing something!

Answer (score -1):

If you're just building an app that would ask for user to agree to a clickwrap using DocuSign Click, you won't need the end-user to authenticate.
I suggest you look at https://myclickwrap.sampleapps.docusign.com/myclickwrap/ and the code in GitHub.
Your app needs the creds to make API calls, but you could use JWT for example with one-time consent and your APP will not make these API calls on behalf of anyone, but just for the one user that the account uses.

All of this is the same in the developer env or production.